# Excel: INDEX and array on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My raw data is a list of students and their grades on Sheet 1.

```
6th Bobby
6th Carl
7th Tommy
8th Bobby
```

I want Sheet 2 to give me a list of students based on the grade I input into cell A1.

example: A1="6th" ... then I get a list with Bobby and Carl.

Here's what I have so far...

```
=INDEX('Sheet 1'!$B$4:$C$7,
            SMALL(IF('Sheet 1'!$B$4:$B$7=$A$1,ROW('Sheet 1'!$B$4:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)),2)
```

(... and I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for the array)

btw... it's not working. I get `#REF!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier way, dynamic, without formulas:

Use a pivot table. Make sure the data has a row with labels in row 1. Click anywhere in the data table and use Insert > Pivot table. Drag the grade into the filter area and the name into the row area. Now you can select a grade in the filter and the names will show in the pivot table.

[image]